# Where do computer graphic engineers look for job ads?

Tags: virtual-reality

This is kind of a meta-question: We are a neuroscience lab looking for an engineer to develop virtual environments for experiments. Since it's not our usual field of job advertisement we do not know where computer graphics people usually look for job ads. A top-3 list of of places you would frequent to look for jobs would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You might try posting ads on game development/programming oriented sites, if owners accept it. I *think* that more people who check out such websites are likely to be interested in graphics programming in general, compared to "regular" job sites (that's true for me, at least ;))

Comment: Interesting, in the institute Im doing my PhD right now the neuroscientists want to build VR enviroment, too. After some discussion and confusion I realised that they do not want to build a VR headset for mice, which I deemed basically impossible, but they want to build a cave https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_automatic_virtual_environment and that should be doable. I would advise to be carefull about the usage of VR which has nowdays quite specific meaning.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic on this site. Please see the [help section](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on what to ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several major Computer Graphics publications that have a jobs section. Try [Siggraph](https://www.siggraph.org/job-board) for example. I'm pretty sure I saw a similar thing for [Eurographics](https://www.eg.org/wp/), but I can't find it right now.
Furthermore, you can look for applicants at the conferences themselves, if you have the resources to do so.

If you accept students that just finish university, you should put up an ad there (or tell the computer graphics professor to spread the word - my professor was kind enough to distribute offers to us every now and then).
Apart from that, you'll probably find most graphics programmers in computer games related fields. Gamasutra has a [jobs section](http://jobs.gamasutra.com/), although I'm not sure they let non-games related companies advertise there.

Moreover, Stackoverflow has a job offers section. I never really used it myself, but it's probably worth looking into. I got quite a few computer graphics related offers, so my guess is that you can advertise specifically to people with tags like *OpenGL* and *Rendering* as their favourite tags.

Comment: Thanks. We actually tried stackexchange, but they told us that they changed their business model and would rather be suited for recurring job offers than for a one time offer.

Answer (score 2):

That's a tough one. This is going to be anecdotal evidence, but in the case of other graphics programmers I know and myself, each of us has a selection of companies we hold in high esteem based on their achievements, and we watch their websites for job postings. Getting on people's "employer wishlists" is difficult for obvious reasons, though, especially if the job isn't "glamourous" like games or film VFX.

What does work sometimes is approaching candidates on LinkedIn (personally, I've had several instances where approaches led to successful processes and then job offers, and I accepted one of them), but I would strongly suggest being as up-front with the details as possible (preferably in the very first message you send). There's nothing more irritating than a recruiter who "will tell you everything, but only over the phone/after we connect".